# How many bananas can a farmer collect at once?

Tags: bloons-td-5

Normally, a banana farmer collects bananas just as the farms produce them:
[image]

But when a round is really fast (like 1 bloon, such as round 24 = 1 camo bloon, round 60 = 1 BFB) and the farms produce all bananas at once, like this:
[image]

And this is how it looks like after the farmer does his work:
[image]

As you can see, the farmer didn't collect all the bananas because he was collecting too many of them and the ones that got outside of range didn't get collected, even though normally they get collected when the bananas land in range of the Banana Farmer OR when the Banana Farm is in range of the Banana Farmer (banana pops out of Farmer's range, but still gets collected in a sec).

My question is: **Is there a limit of how many bananas** (or banana boxes) **can the farmer collect at once?** If yes, how many? If no, what is the cause of this happening?

Comment: I really hope the account that answers this is called Mr. Tallyman

Answer (score 1):

The monkey farmer does not collect bananas based on where they originate from. He automatically collects bananas based on where the bananas land. It looks like he's collecting them immediately, but really he's collecting them the second they spawn because they are going to land within his range.

Comment: Then explain why does the farmer collect bananas(normally, one by one) when they go off his range for a fraction of a second and come back? I think that the landing spot depends only if a farm isn't in the farmers range. I am using the mobile version, so it may be a bit different on the PC version.

Comment: I'm sorry I must have missed this. I believe this is a graphics setting. The higher you have the graphics the more animated things are. The bananas must have an animation that springs them out and pulls them back in like a yo-yo affect or something.

Comment: Yes, so the farmer brings them back from the spot they land, because it was produced in a banana farm in the range of the farmer That means, the bananas that would land out of the farmer's range are still being collected. Maybe consider editing your question so I can accept it.

Comment: Perhaps it the time it took for the farmer to "sense" the banana took longer than the banana landing outside it's range. So even though the banana is was outside the farmer's range, the farmer could still collect it. (That's only my theory, not sure if it's true or not)